# wget() to /tmp/wget produces "EMFILE, too many open files"

Tags: node.js

I am monitoring a list of IP using wget() from nodejs, using "node-wget".

The exact command is

```
    wget( {
        url:  szTargetIP,     // as "http://10.139.238.167
        dest: '/tmp/wget/',
        timeout: 2000    
    },
```

Right after scanning the file (as /tmp/wget/10.139.238.167), I do

```
fs.unlink( szIPfn, (err) => {          // delete file
    if (err) {
        if ( err.code === 'ENOENT' ) {
            mConsole( '--- file '+ szIPfn +' does not exist' ) ;
        } else {
            throw err ; // fatal error : stop
        } ;
    } else {
        mConsole( '+++ successfully deleted ' + szIPfn ) ;
    } ;
} ) ; // unlink
```

I always log " +++ successfully deleted /tmp/wget/10.139.238.167"

Unfortunatelly, after some time of running my app.js, 
I get "EMFILE, too many open files"

The directory "/tmp/wget" is empty, but ... "lsof | grep wget" displays

```
/tmp/wget/10.139.238.167 (deleted)
```

Any ideas ?

*** complete code ***

```
wget( {
        url:  szTargetIP,  
        dest: '/tmp/wget/',
        timeout: 2000       
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        szNow = genTimeStamp() ; // get timestamp
        if (error) {
            console.log('--- wget() error:');
        } else {
            console.log('+++ wget() ok');
        } ; // no error = wget() ok
    }
) ; // wget()

var szIPfn = '/tmp/wget/' + iWget_IP ; 
fs.unlink( szIPfn, (err) => {
```

Comment: I think that you could have `ulimit -a` problems (too many file descriptor open). In this case you have a memory leak somewhere. Could you add more code on how you save the data after the wget?

Comment: hi : "ulimit -a" is set to default 1024

Comment: cant add more code, as node-wget does it all

Comment: don't you use a callback in your `wget` command ? What do you do with the received datas ?

Comment: just added callback in main body, but I do nothing with the received data, just want to know if IP answers or not, to monitor ...

Answer (score 2):

`node-wget` uses `fs.createWriteStream()` function which, according to the [API Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options), automaticly close the destination file on `error` or `finish` event.

`node-wget` also uses `request` module which never emit the `finish` event but `complete`.

**Then the destination file of your wget command is never closed.**

Simply add something like :

```
var szIPfn = '/tmp/wget/' + iWget_IP ; 

fs.close(szIPfn, err => {
  if (err) thow err;

  fs.unlink( szIPfn, (err) => {         // delete file
    if (err) {
      if ( err.code === 'ENOENT' ) {
        mConsole( '--- file '+ szIPfn +' does not exist' ) ;
      } else {
        throw err; // fatal error : stop
      }
    }else{
      mConsole( '+++ successfully deleted ' + szIPfn ) ;
    }
  }); // unlink
}); // close
```

Comment: gonna try it .. in 5 minutes!

Comment: mr DUN32 - fs.close() needs a FD, which I do not have, as I did not "open" the file

Comment: fs.unlink() gets a "path" ... which I do have

Comment: Ok, I understand... but I guess that's the problem. I had it once, that error, I add to fork and edit the module to handle closing files.

Comment: anyway, as I dont want the data, I will try to use THE SAME file for all wget() operations *** :-))